# Replace Integrate new api of twitter in iOS?

Tags: ios, twitter

In my App, I have used MGTwitter Engine. I used twitter in many files in app.

Now there is Twitter 1.1 is announced.

I want to know where I can download API 1.1 for iOS.

What are changes I need to do in my existing code?

I tried to read the documentation of twitter, but new version looks much different than previous which I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Based on latest fragmentation report - http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/20/apple-now-charting-app-store-ios-fragmentation-just-like-googles-android there is no need in implementing Twitter as external library/SDK.

Currently there is more than 93% users on iOS 6 and plus 5% iOS 5. You can safely use internal iOS integration of Twitter and cover 98% users.

Read here about this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html

If you will still want to use external library - please se the ShareKit https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit I believe that they have already implemented 1.1 API. But since I don't use their library I'm not 100% sure.